# Foundataion 5 ajax range slider (re)initialistaion settings

Tags: javascript, ajax, slider, zurb-foundation

How to initialize foundation.slider.js and reinitialize settings via ajax? For example I have range slider with limit by step equal 5, after push button ajax response has new step equal 7 and range slider step have to changed to 7.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `foundation.js` and `jquery` in your codebase do the following

1, have a callback ajax function

2, set your new value via the foundation call  function on the slider and pass in `'slider', 'set_value'` and the new slider value as an argument.

```
var new_value = xxx;
$('slider').foundation('slider', 'set_value', new_value);
```

`xxx` should be the result of your ajax function